# What is the equivelent of "openssl dgst -sha1 -sign"?

Tags: openssl, rsa, digital-signature, sha1, phpseclib

I have scoured Google for how to implement the equivalent of "openssl dgst -sha1 -sign" in the phpseclib PHP library without much success.

I need to implement the following openssl command-line in PHP

**openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.rsa.pem -out signature.out.bin data.in.txt**

I understand that "dgst -sha1 -sign" will 
1) create a hash
2) ASN1 encodes the hash 
3) signs the ASN1 encoded hash with private key,

Using phpseclib ~2.0, I have gotten as far as

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Crypt\Hash;
use phpseclib\File\ASN1;

$rsa = new RSA();
$hash = new Hash();
$asn1 = new ASN1();

$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents($this->privateKeyFile));

$sha1Hash = $hash->hash($data);
$privatekey = $rsa->getPrivateKey();
$encodedsha1Hash = $asn1->encodeDER($privatekey, ???? );

$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$dataSignature = $rsa->sign($encodedsha1Hash);

$rsa->verify($encodedsha1Hash, $dataSignature);
```

I am a cryptographic newbie, but I'm surprised this was such a difficult topic to find an answer for. Can anyone help?

Comment: You didn't actually include a question. It's not clear where you a stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html#rsasigpkcs1,p1openssl,p2phpseclib.

In your code you're doing this:

```
$sha1Hash = $hash->hash($data);
$privatekey = $rsa->getPrivateKey();
$encodedsha1Hash = $asn1->encodeDER($privatekey, ???? );

$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$dataSignature = $rsa->sign($encodedsha1Hash);
```

Replace all that with this:

```
$dataSignature = $rsa->sign($data);
```

Also, don't do this:

```
$rsa->verify($encodedsha1Hash, $dataSignature);
```

Do this:

```
$rsa->verify($data, $dataSignature);
```